# How can I automatically launch an app from Safari without required permission?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipados

I’m currently working on a smart mirror prototype and for that I use an iPad Pro that is connected to a screen. On the iPad I installed my Unity app. Now I need to be able to automatically open the app from the browser (I’ll implement additional things in HTML that runs locally on a SimpleHTTPServer). I used a custom URL scheme to do this and it works as intended. But how can I disable the prompt that asks for permission to launch the app? I will not have access to the iPad once it's attached to the frame of the prototype, so I need it to open the app without me having to manually click on "Open"

Comment: @matt When I type in the URL scheme a window opens asking "Open ...?". The app opens as soon as I manually click on open

Comment: @matt It's just a thing of typing in example:// in the address bar of the browser. When I do this it tries to open the app but I need to manually click "Open"

Comment: And universal links are much better than custom schemes.

Comment: @matt How does this help me now? I need to open the app without giving permission, how can I do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243411/discussion-between-codedbyim-and-matt).

Comment: Short answer is you cannot disable this prompt. It is part of iOS in built security to ensure users aren't misdirected